# Нужна ли запятая перед "и" (обоснование)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастный-оборот

Он подстегнул грифа, и, заложив крутой вираж, понесся к земле. По моему мнению, не нужна, но вот почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая не нужна. Союз *и* объединяет однородные члены, в составе которых есть деепричастный оборот. Запятая после *и* выделяет деепричастный оборот.

Comment: Уточнение: деепричастный оборот относится только к одному из однородных сказуемых. А в остальном все верно.

Comment: @М_Г, да, вы правы.